Server Timing API - There's undefined and unexpected png on my running browser
I got a weird issue when I was working on html, js.Below is what I got, the point is that when I sent the same code to other computer, it works well with the data, and I also got a line of "Phisherman loaded...", which not included in my codes.
I'm not sure if this is because I have timer in my codes because I saw there's a hint linked to Server Timing API though I haven't connected to any API in my codes.
Also I cleand the cache, changed the brower, re-start the laptop, but it still exists.

In addition, I can also see two unexpected pngs on the browser/content.js(no idea what it is)
chrome-extension://pnhojlpkdnfhikpofiijpojgpejkdgpj/images/icon48.png
chrome-extension://pnhojlpkdnfhikpofiijpojgpejkdgpj/images/cross_32.png
I don't think I have such img in my codes.Besides the undefined value that stopped me processing my data, my timer is also very messy while both work in other computer...

You should focus on one specific question. Concerning the pngs: do you have any browser extensions enabled?

As things work on another computer, have you checked that you are picking up the right version of things on your computer - have you cleared cache for example?

@tobifasc, I disabled all.

@AHaworth, yes, the version is the same and I did clear cache.
